# Storing a grouped UITableView in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to store a grouped UITableView in an array (eg all the individual cells) so that i can retain which cells the user has tapped (and add the check accessory to it). Every time i try and restore the cells, i end up with the most recent cells to have been displayed (ie. the cells that have just appeared at the bottom of the screen appear at the top when scrolling back up.
i cant figure out hot to do this correctly so any help is very welcome
thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyManager *dataStore = (MyManager* )[MyManager sharedManager];

NSNumber *dif = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:-1];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    dif = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
} else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    dif = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
} else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    dif = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];
} else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    dif = [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
}


if ([dataStore.masterArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row+[dif intValue])]==@"0") {
//array is initalised with 16 strings of @"0", just to fill it  


static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";      
NSArray *listData =[self.data objectForKey:
                    [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];       
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView
                          dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {           
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
}
NSUInteger Row = [indexPath row];
cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:Row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [dataStore.masterArray replaceObjectAtIndex:(indexPath.row + [dif intValue]) withObject:cell];

    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:Row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
    }
else {
UITableViewCell *cell = [dataStore.masterArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row+[dif intValue])];


    return cell;
}

}
```

i would assume that this code should check to see if there is a cell at the index, if no then make and display one (this works fine). If the cell does exist, pull it out of the array an display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that cells are not all created at once. They are created and destroyed when necessary. If the cells go out of view, they may be destroyed to save memory. Instead of storing the cells themselves in an array, store a boolean value in an array. Then when the cell is created for a specific row, use the bool value out of the array to determine if it should be checked.

Comment: Wow, all that time i wasted on this when the solution was so simple, thank you for that, works like a charm

Comment: hhaha, well, it helps to have a fresh perspective. Glad I could help.